# How to convert SpecFlow table to array of strings

Tags: c#, specflow

I am generating content for a text file and trying to test the output with a SpecFlow table. My `Then` statement looks like this:

```
Then the content should be 
| Line           |
| This is Line 1 |
| This is Line 2 |
| etc...         |
```

I'm turning this into an array of strings in the Step file like this:

```
[Then(@"the content should be")]
public void ThenTheContentShouldBe(Table table)
{
    string[] expectedLines = table.Rows.Select(x => x.Values.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
    ...
}
```

This will give me an array of strings with 3 elements, ignoring the first "Line" as the table header. But it feels a bit awkward. Is there a better way to turn this into an array of `string`? Bonus points if it also can convert into arrays immutable types like `int`, etc.

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: Mainly, if I had a class `Foo` with a single `string` property called `Line`, I could just do `table.CreateSet<Foo>();`. I guess I was hoping for a clever way to use the `CreateSet` extension method.

Comment: doesn't `table.CreateSet<Foo>().Select(f => f.Line).ToArray()` work?

Comment: i tried `table.CreateSet<string>().ToArray()` and get expected number of array  results.... but all empty strings. DOH!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could write your own extension

```
public static class MyTableExtenstions
    {
        public static string[] AsStrings(this Table table, string column)
        {
            return table.Rows.Select(row => row[column]).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

then

```
string[] expectedLines = table.AsStrings("Line");
```

Comment: Being very lazy i just did `var results = table.Rows.Select(r => r[0]).ToArray()`